# python type casting based on reference list type for comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a better way to copy the type of database table column to corresponding data read form expat parser. so that I can compare the data, instead of string(xml data) to other type(database column type like date, datetime, int, float).

I don't want to convert the database table column type to string for comparison.

Example:

```
select emp_num, emp_name, date_of_Join from employee
```

From Database:

```
(6546,'John',datetime.date(2018, 4, 5))
```

From XML Parser i constructed below list:

```
['6546','John', '20180405')]
```

Now I need to apply the types from database data to XML data.

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: if you run a select query on a table(using pyodbc) the data which you get is based on table column. I am reading the same data from xml as str. Now I need to compare the list from table and a list from xml (which is string) is failing due to type mismatch.

Comment: You can examine the type in the database result and use some pre-defined function to cast the XML value to the same type; e.g. `if isinstance(db_value, int): xml_value = int(xml_value)`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to inspect each data in a row with isinstance,
So took column name and column type from cursor.columns() function.

then in table-entity class '__init__()' method formed a dictionary using column name as key having lambda as value of the dict for type casting

using cursor.columns object iterated for colname(column[index 3]) and coltype (column[index 5]).

```
#In table object '__init__()' 

self.castcol=dict()
if coltype='char':
   self.castcol[colname]= lambda x : str(x)
if coltype='int' or coltype='numeric':
   self.castcol[colname]= lambda x : int(x)
if coltype='datetime':
   self.castcol[colname]= lambda x : <datetime cast>
```

Now applied / transformed the above dict pattern and then compared the data between xml and db if mismatch then inserted the record in db.

thank you very much **deceze** for your response.